# Поиск слов в предложениях

Tags: python

Хочу сделать алгоритм поиска как показано ниже

```
a = ['Founder in iosg.vc','DM me for VC / AMA hosting services!','https://t.me/forexblvckChild','VC']
b = ['web3','pro','vc']
for i in a:
    if any(x.lower() == i.lower() for x in b):
        print(i)
    else:
        pass
>>> VC
```

Сейчас оно выводит только `VC` когда оно отдельное слово

```
a = ['Founder in iosg.vc','DM me for VC / AMA hosting services!','https://t.me/forexblvckChild','VC']
b = ['web3','pro','vc']
for i in a:
    if any(x.lower() in i.lower() for x in b):
        print(i)
    else:
        pass
>>> Founder in iosg.vc
    DM me for VC / AMA hosting services!
    https://t.me/forexblvckChild
    VC
```

А тут оно выводит все где есть `VC`

Мне нужно что-то среднее

Надо чтобы он выводил

```
>>> Founder in iosg.vc
    DM me for VC / AMA hosting services!
    VC
```

И чтоб он пропускал `https://t.me/forexblvckChild`

мой алгоритм берет это изза того что там есть `https://t.me/forexbl<<vc>>kChild`

Как такое сделать?

Comment: regex c шаблоном `\bvc\b` будет отбирать только отделные слова vc

Comment: или разбейте по пробелу, слэшу и тп строку и проверяйте наличие vc в полученном списке

Comment: @splash58 а как можно туда добавить слова из переменно просто там может быть не одно а несколько слов

Comment: если вы разобъете строку в список, то проверять надо, как вы во втором случае проверяли

Comment: @splash58 а нету идеек для того чтоб ответы были как в RegEx

Comment: да сколько угодно - или в regex реализуется очень просто,

Comment: можно replace-ом заменить всю пунктуацию и цифры на пробелы а потом разделять